# API Call working on postman but not in curl or Salesforce Apex

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex

I am having trouble performing a successful API Rest call via apex. The service I'm trying to send a request to has no security layer whatsoever.

I can successfuly do the call on postman but if I try it via curl I get an error 401.

I tried it via Apex in two different ways and getting 500 and 405.

Again, the service has no security layer nor requiers additional parameters.

POSTMAN:

![postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUqme.png)

CURL

`curl -v -X POST '<URL>/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=1030&deploy=1&compid=8305111_SB1&h=a9b851a89fbedd8d239d' -H 'Content-Type:application/json'`

`` `* Trying <IP>... ``

- `TCP_NODELAY set`
- `Connected to <URL> (<IP>) port 443 (#0)`
- `ALPN, offering h2`
- `ALPN, offering http/1.1`
- `successfully set certificate verify locations:`
- `CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
  `CApath: /etc/ssl/certs`
- `TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):`
- `TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):`
- `TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):`
- `TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):`
- `TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):`
- `TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):`
- `TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):`
- `TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):`
- `SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`
- `ALPN, server accepted to use h2`
- `Server certificate:`
- `subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Redwood City; O=Oracle Corporation; CN=<CN>`
- `start date: Nov 25 00:00:00 2023 GMT`
- `expire date: Nov 27 23:59:59 2024 GMT`
- `subjectAltName: host "<URL>" matched cert's "*.<CN>"`
- `issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1`
- `SSL certificate verify ok.`
- `Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use`
- `Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)`
- `Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0`
- `Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x557c84893630)`

> `POST /app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=1030&deploy=1&compid=8305111_SB1&h=a9b851a89fbedd8d239d HTTP/2`
> `Host: <URL>`
> `user-agent: curl/7.68.0`
> `accept:` *`/`*
> `content-type:application/json`

- `TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):`
- `TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):`
- `old SSL session ID is stale, removing`
- `Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!`
  `< HTTP/2 411`
  `< server: AkamaiGHost`
  `< mime-version: 1.0`
  `< content-type: text/html`
  `< content-length: 222`
  `< expires: Sat, 13 Jan 2024 06:51:15 GMT`
  `< x-reference-error: 7.a4371602.1705128675.a94e38f`
  `< date: Sat, 13 Jan 2024 06:51:15 GMT`
  `< akamai-grn: 0.a4371602.1705128675.a94e38f`
  `<`

``
Bad Request{

```
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reference&#32;&#35;7&#46;a4371602&#46;1705128675&#46;a94e38f


* Connection #0 to host  left intact`
```

As for the apex code, this is what I'm executing:

```
public static void testCode7(boolean paramsInURL){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    String endpoint = '<URL>';
    
    if(paramsInURL){
        endpoint +='?script=1030';
        endpoint += '&deploy=1';
        endpoint += '&compid=8305111_SB1';
        endpoint += '&h=a9b851a89fbedd8d239d';
    }else{
        request.setHeader('script','1030');
        request.setHeader('deploy','1');
        request.setHeader('compid','8305111_SB1');
        request.setHeader('h','a9b851a89fbedd8d239d');
    }    

    request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    request.setBody('{}');
    
    
    HttpResponse res = http.send(request);
}
```

When sending params in the url, I get:

```
RESPONSE --\> System.HttpResponse\[Status=Method Not Allowed, StatusCode=405\]

body:Method Not Allowed

status:Method Not Allowed

header keys:\[ "X-Cache", "Strict-Transport-Security", "Cache-Control", "Akamai-GRN",

When sending them on the header:

23:15:53.1 (3306629)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|\[204\]|System.HttpRequest\[Endpoint=\<URL\>/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl, Method=POST\]

23:15:53.1 (705533129)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|\[204\]|System.HttpResponse\[Status=Internal Server Error, StatusCode=500\]

23:15:53.1 (705934088)|USER_DEBUG|\[205\]|DEBUG|RESPONSE --\> System.HttpResponse\[Status=Internal Server Error, StatusCode=500\]
```

Notice

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/ui/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/ui/jquery/jquery_isolation.js?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/FieldLevelHelp.jsp?JSP_VER=1&NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15&buildver=30872'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/help_service/3801826802.js?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLUtil.jsp?JSP_VER=1&NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15&buildver=30872'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLUtil.js?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15&buildver=30872'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLUIWidgets.jsp?JSP_VER=1&NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15&buildver=30872'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/legacy_widgets/862947475.js?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/help_center_service/3441369224.js?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/legacy_apputil/1916206691.js?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/javascript/NLAppUtil.jsp?JSP_VER=1&NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15&buildver=30872'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='/uirefresh/script/global.js__NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15.nlqs?NS_VER=2023.2&minver=15&buildver=30872'></script>
```

Notice


 
This request is missing a required parameter.
 
 




function page_init() {
}



```

status:Internal Server Error:

```
DEBUG|header keys:\[ "X-Cache", "Akamai-GRN", "Connection", "Pragma", "Date", "Strict-Transport-Security", "Cache-Control", "NS_RTIMER_COMPOSITE", "Vary", "Expires", "Content-Length", "X-N-OperationId", "Content-Type" \]
```

Comment: You're getting an error in curl even if you run the curl command generated straight from postman's code button? You sure it's not a proxy / whitelisted IPs problem?